# what is the relation between solving a polynomial and the decomposition series of its galois group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Can someone please explain me what is the exact relation between solving a polynomial by resolvents, and its corresponding galois decomposition series? Where and how do the normal subgroups and the cyclic quotient groups come in and what exact implication does it bring? I have been obsessed with this issue for weeks and I simply cannot grasp it. I am mainly interested in sketching a *unified* way to solve polynomials of degree 2, 3, 4, and greater than 5 when solvable. Maybe you could give an exact, step by step procedure for solving the cubic, and highlighting what happens at every step (i.e., when I go to a "lower" subgroup from its decomposition series). If you can, a more intuitive approach would be helpful. Not necessarily rigurous.

UPTADE: I am not referring to the theoretical part on field extension, but on the more practical part, how do these concepts come in in actual working out of the solution step by step.

Comment: This question requires a very detailed answer, that is already contained in some excellent books. I'd recommend Jacobson's Basic Algebra I, or Kaplansky's Fields and Rings.

Comment: The connection passes through Kummer theory (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer_theory). This should be in most books on Galois theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found Dr. Salamone's videos on the subject very helpful. In particular check out his three-part series called *A Cubic Workout* in which he explains in simple terms how the cubic is solved using its decomposition series.

*A Cubic Workout*   [Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sg97_Azxvjo),  [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDI8LXIpAa8), [Part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdwy6KP1WcM).   All three as a [list](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sg97_Azxvjo&list=PLL0ATV5XYF8Cxfe2VOHplTCmFswaEP_VE).

Comment: Excellent! I never thought about searching it on Youtube, I only searched articles and books. Many thanks, sir!

Comment: Too bad I can give you only one vote, it's exactly what i have been searcing for!